# How to find tuple with minimal item in array of tuple

Tags: c#, tuples

i have this code:

```
(int, int)[] tupleArray = { (3, 2), (4, 1) };
```

Tuple with minimal element in array is (4, 1), but this code

```
tupleArray.Min();
```

returns (3, 2). I think this method compares only between Item1. Is there a simple solution that solves my problem?

Comment: `tupleArray.OrderBy(x => x.Item1 + x.Item2).First()`?  I'm kinda surprised `Min` even works with a value tuple.

Comment: The default comparer for a value tuple will compare on the first item, then if those are equal then the second and so on.  I assume you want to compare on the sum?

Comment: @juharr same result, because 3 + 2 == 4 + 1 and i don`t like solution with slow sort. I think there is a faster solution

Comment: You can Aggregate.

Comment: So you want the tuple with the minimum overall value?  Then you'd want `tupleArray.OrderBy(x => Math.Min(x.Item1, x.Item2)).First()`.  Or you can use a for loop to find it or MoreLinq's `MinBy` if you think sorting is too slow.  Hint: `OrderBy` might not be as bad as you think.

Comment: There is a faster solution! `(int, int)? min = null; foreach (var tuple in tupleArray) if (min == null || tuple.Item1 < min.Value.Item1 || tuple.Item1 < min.Value.Item2 || tuple.Item2 < min.Value.Item1 || tuple.Item2 < min.Value.Item2) min = tuple;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OrderBy` combined with `Math.Min`

```
var min = tupleArray
    .OrderBy(t => Math.Min(t.Item1, t.Item2))
    .First()
```

Or `Aggregate` which should be faster:

```
Func<(int, int), int> min = t => Math.Min(t.Item1, t.Item2); // just not to repeat comparison
var min = tupleArray.Aggregate((acc, t) =>  min(t) > min(acc) ? acc: t);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use that, which is fast:

```
(int, int)[] tupleArray = { (3, 2), (4, 1) };

(int, int) min = (int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);

foreach ( var item in tupleArray )
  if ( item.Item1 < min.Item1 || item.Item2 < min.Item2
    || item.Item1 < min.Item2 || item.Item2 < min.Item1 )  // Additional tests from @itsme86 
    min = item;

Console.WriteLine(min);
```

*Output*

```
(4, 1)
```

Comment: Or you could just do `if(Math.Min(item.Item1,item.Item2) < Math.Min(min.Item1,min.Item2))`

Comment: It will add 2 CPU proc calls and associated CPU stack push/pop, that will slow the loop, isn't it ?

Comment: I mean if you don't believe it compiler optimizations sure.

Comment: I don't believe. I know. And I can check with ILSpy: `IL_0053: call int32 [mscorlib]System.Math::Min(int32, int32)`. Debug or release. Some [Blt_S](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.blt_s) opcodes always will be faster (ASM JL, see [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html))

Answer (score 1):

An [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) variant, with an inlined Tuple (`(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue)`) used for both comparison and storage, similar to what Guru Stron posted.
`tupleArray` is declared as a named Tuple. I've added some more values to the array to make more clear what these methods can return.

This will return the first element in the array with the minimum value `(4, 1)`.

```
(int i1, int i2)[] tupleArray = { (3, 2), (4, 1), (1, 4), (2, 2) };

var min = tupleArray.Aggregate((int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue), (tm, t)
    => (Math.Min(t.i1, t.i2) < Math.Min(tm.Item1, tm.Item2)) ? t : tm);
```

If you already have a recipient that should be used for comparison, you can also use [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select):

```
(int i1, int i2) min = (int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);
min = tupleArray.Select(t => 
    { return min = (Math.Min(t.i1, t.i2) < Math.Min(min.i1, min.i2)) ? t : min; }).Last();
```

<sub>(Here, the value assigned to the **`min`**, `(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue)`, could be a value previously stored, declared as the `tupleArray` collection)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`MinBy`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.3/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_MinBy__2.htm) operator, from the [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) library.

> Returns the minimal elements of the given sequence, based on the given projection.

```
public static IExtremaEnumerable<TSource> MinBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> selector);
```

Usage example:

```
var minTuple = tupleArray.MinBy(t => Math.Min(t.Item1, t.Item2)).First();
```

Btw the `MinBy` was returning a single value in the pre-3.0 versions of the library ([citation](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/issues/524)).